# Mappend (a1,b1) and (a2,b2) into (a1+a2, b1+b2)

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, monoids

I recall this is very basic, and could simply be done with pattern matching even through a lambda like `(\a b -> (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b) )  (1,2) (3,4)`. However, I think there should be ways provided by the Haskell standard library to do things like this. The definition of `mappend` for `(a,b)` type as Monoids looks quite similar. But doing the following didn't work:

```
(1,2) `mappend` (3,4)
```

Any Haskell way of adding two 2-tuples?

Comment: You can use the `Sum` newtype that encodes a `Monoid` instance for numbers for this.  Numbers can often belong to multiple `Monoid` instances, hence why there isn't one defined for them by default.  You have to choose which one you want to use.  I might also suggest you look into the `Control.Arrow` module, as what you want to do can be described fairly easily with those combinators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers are monoids, that's not the problem. The problem is that there are *two different, equally good ways* in which they are monoids – addition is only one, the other is multiplication. The standard library thus decided to not give a monoid instance at all, which I think is a good decision.

Haskell allows packing types in *newtype wrappers* to select an instance without affecting the underlying type. The two different monoid instances are available in base:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> case (Sum 1, Sum 2)<>(Sum 3, Sum 4) of (Sum a, Sum b) -> (a,b)
(4,6)
```

A bit awkward. There are a couple of ways in which you can make this more concise (I don't really *recommend* any of them; see bottom for a better solution). First, as Jon remarks in the comments, if the tuples contain just plain number literals like in your example, there's no need to explicitly wrap them in the `Sum` constructor, since there is an instance `Num a => Num (Sum a)` an number literals are polymorphic, i.e. the following will do:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> case (1,2) <> (3,4) of (Sum x, Sum y) -> (x,y)
(4,6)
```

however, if the types of the tuple elements are already fixed...

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> let [a,b,c,d] = [1,2,3,4] :: [Int]
Prelude Data.Monoid> case (a,b) <> (c,d) of (Sum x, Sum y) -> (x,y) :: (Int,Int) 
<interactive>:6:25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Sum Int’
    In the pattern: Sum x
    In the pattern: (Sum x, Sum y)
    In a case alternative: (Sum x, Sum y) -> (x, y) :: (Int, Int)
```

Here you need to be explicit where the wrapping should happen. You can still briefen it a bit by using [type-safe coercions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html), which allow you to wrap all the elements of an entire container (tuples, lists, maps, arrays...) in a newtype such as `Sum` in one go (and in *O* (1) time&space, which can also be quite a bonus).

```
Prelude Data.Monoid Data.Coerce> case coerce (a,b) <> coerce (c,d) of (Sum x, Sum y) -> (x,y) :: (Int,Int)
(4,6)
```

Even briefer, and less reliant on local signatures, could be an approach using the [`Newtype` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2/docs/Control-Newtype.html):

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> :m +Control.Newtype
Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Newtype> :m +Control.Arrow
Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Newtype Control.Arrow> :simpleprompt 
> ala (Sum***Sum) foldMap [(1,2), (3,4)]
(4,6)
```

...however, as I was rather surprised to find out now, the `newtype` library doesn't come with the tuple instance that's necessary for this. You can define it yourself though:

```
> :set -XFunctionalDependencies -XUndecidableInstances
> instance (Newtype a α, Newtype b β) => Newtype (a,b) (α,β) where {pack=pack***pack; unpack=unpack***unpack}
```

---

If you really only need the additive monoid, I recommend you instead use a dedicated *class* for addition: [`AdditiveGroup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.4/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html)

```
Prelude Data.AdditiveGroup> (1,2)^+^(3,4)
(4,6)
```

Comment: Looks like my answer, but I feel like it is a bit complicated than simply just using the lambda :/

Comment: You also don’t need to repeat `Sum` everywhere, because there’s an `instance (Num a) => Num (Sum a)`, so inference can get it as long as it’s not ambiguous. For example, `case (1, 2) <> (3, 4) of (Sum x, Sum y) -> (x, y)`.

Comment: @JonPurdy right, but that `Num` instance won't help if the tuples contain not just number literals (which is almost certainly not the actual use case) but variables whose type is already rigid.

Answer (score 3):

If you allow me to overlook the role of `Monoid` in your question, here are a couple ways to express it in terms of [`Biapplicative` from *bifunctors*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html), which is a pretty straightforward generalisation of `Applicative` to `Bifunctor`s:

```
GHCi> import Data.Biapplicative
GHCi> :t bimap
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
GHCi> :t (<<*>>)
(<<*>>) :: Biapplicative p => p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
GHCi> bimap (+) (+) (1,2) <<*>> (3,4)
(4,6)
GHCi> :t biliftA2
biliftA2
  :: Biapplicative w =>
     (a -> b -> c) -> (d -> e -> f) -> w a d -> w b e -> w c f
GHCi> biliftA2 (+) (+) (1,2) (3,4)
(4,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also can be done in some simple and stupid but fancy way (though this approach requires turning your *Haskell* into *Lisp*).

```
{-# LANGUAGE PostfixOperators #-}

import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)
import Data.Semigroup (Sum (..), (<>))

(+?) :: (a, b) -> (Sum a, Sum b)
(+?) = bimap Sum Sum

(+!) :: (Sum a, Sum b) -> (a, b)
(+!) = bimap getSum getSum
```

And then in `ghci`:

```
ghci> (( ((1,2) +?) <> ((3,4) +?)) +!)
(4,6)
```

Comment: This would work with far fewer parenthesis if you called the functions e.g. `bisum` and `getBisum` instead of using postfix syntax.